# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

Have an existing Maven JSF project that has been running fine for months now, and I need to add some new dependencies to it.

When I add a new dependency, it compiles fine, but throws a NoClassDefFoundError when it tries to execute any code that uses the new dependency.
In this case, the new dependency is the PayPal SDK.

I am using IntelliJ as my IDE and it is in control of compiling/deploying the project.

Any ideas what I can do to solve this?

**POM:**

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ... (lots of other dependencies here)
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
       <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Alpha9</version>
        </plugin>
```

**Java:**

```
package com.inmatic.kico.paypal.business.boundary;

import com.inmatic.kico.accounts.companies.business.entity.Companies;
import com.paypal.api.payments.*;
import com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Stateless
public class PayPalFacade implements Serializable {
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PayPalFacade.class.getSimpleName());

    private static String PAYPAL_CLIENTID = "...";
    private static String PAYPAL_SECRET = "...";

    public void doCreditCardPayment(Companies company, int cardType, String cardName, String cardNumber, int cardExpiryMonth, int cardExpiryYear, int cardCVV2, double total, double tax) {
        String firstName = cardName.indexOf(" ")>-1 ? cardName.substring(0, cardName.indexOf(" ")) : cardName;
        String lastName = cardName.indexOf(" ")>-1 ? cardName.substring(cardName.indexOf(" ") + 1) : "";

        CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();    //exception is thrown on this line
        //creditCard.setBillingAddress();
        creditCard.setCvv2(cardCVV2);
        creditCard.setExpireMonth(cardExpiryMonth);
        creditCard.setExpireYear(cardExpiryYear);
        creditCard.setFirstName(firstName);
        creditCard.setLastName(lastName);
        creditCard.setNumber(cardNumber);
        creditCard.setType(cardType==0 ? "visa" : "mastercard");
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: JBAS014580: Unexpected Error
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at com.inmatic.kico.paypal.business.boundary.PayPalFacade$$$view84.doCreditCardPayment(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:414)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
at com.inmatic.kico.paypal.business.boundary.PayPalFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.doCreditCardPayment(Unknown Source)
at com.inmatic.kico.accounts.companies.presentation.CompanySubscribe_View.subscribe(CompanySubscribe_View.java:223)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:286)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at com.inmatic.kico.common.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:53)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/paypal/api/payments/CreditCard
at com.inmatic.kico.paypal.business.boundary.PayPalFacade.doCreditCardPayment(PayPalFacade.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273)
... 103 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.paypal.api.payments.CreditCard from [Module "deployment.KicoLocal.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
... 139 more
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I tried with no scope, compile scope and provide scope and none seem to make a difference.

Comment: I have added the full stack trace now.

Comment: Is this a simple WAR deployment that contains EJBs?

Comment: Yes it is a web application, packaged as a war and running on Wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lies here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Firstly as others have said, you should try to remove the `compile` scope and completely rebuild your project.

Secondly, never use `LATEST` !! Always specify the version. Using "latest" violates the principle of reproducible builds. It might build fine today but not tomorrow if the developer changes the API's (it happens).

So, remove the `<scope>`, lock it down to a specific version (not `LATEST`), rebuild the project and do `mvn clean install`.

Comment: I have removed the scope, set the version to 1.13.0 and did a clean and install in IntelliJ, but still the same problem.

Comment: Which specific class (with package) is not found?